# Question about intel assembly

Tags: assembly

I am trying to work my way through an Intel assembly file and I ran into a bit of code I don't understand.

```
# Save current stack pointer to old thread's stack, if any.
movl SWITCH_CUR(%esp), %eax
movl %esp, (%eax,%edx,1)
```

I understand that the first line moves the value of `12` offset from register `%esp` into the register `%eax`.

But I don't understand what the second line does it moves `%esp` into what.

Is `(%eax,%edx,1)` a logical `and` operation? Or addition?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is

```
mov %esp, (%eax + %edx * 1)
```

The number can be 1, 2, 4 or 8.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

Answer (score 2):

`(%eax,%edx,1)` refers to the location in memory whose address is formed by adding the value in `%eax` to the value in `%edx`.  The 1 is the scale factor which doesn't actually "matter" because it is 1.

**ADDENDUM**

In detail (in case anyone else lands on this page):

```
mov %esp, %edx              # move contents of esp into edx
```

Assuming edx contains 100 and eax contains 20:

```
mov %esp, (%edx)            # move contents of esp in address 100
mov %esp, (%edx,%eax)       # ... into address 100 + 20 = 120
mov %esp, (%edx,%eax,4)     # ... into address 100 + (20*4) = 180
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is a lot more clear now, so if for instance the scale factor was 2 then it would be `(%eax + %edx) * 2`??

Comment: No, this kind of addressing is specifically designed for accessing arrays. The first operand is the base address, and only the second operand (the array index) is multiplied by the constant.

Comment: @Hunter Roland is correct.  In x86, addressing is BASE + INDEX * SCALE.  BASE is any general purpose register except %esp, INDEX is any general purpose register, and the SCALE is 1, 2, 4 or 8.  The notation in ATT syntax is `(base,index,scale)`.  In Intel sytax we write `[BASE+INDEX*SCALE]`.